# Awk script to find string based on particular pattern and look for its corresponding rows and build another output file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

Experts,
Need your support for this awk script.
we have only one input file, all these column 1 and column 2 are in same file and have to do lookup for values in one file(column1 and column2) but output we need in another file
**Need to grep row whose string contains 9K in column 1** and then grep its corresponding row in column 2. Suppose check for 9K1 then grep A1, check for A1 in column 1 if not, output result as shown in below expected output file
Then again check for 9K1, grep A2, look for A2 in column1, if found grep its corresponding row value B2.
Now check for B2 value in column 1, then grep for C2 instead of A2 as we have already considered previously in lookup.
Now look for C2 in column and grep D2 instead of B2

This needs to be checked for all rows in column 1 that contains 9K, as there can be rows with value 9K2, 9K3, 9K4 in column 1 with corresponding data in column2.

Input file :

```
9K1,A1
9K1,A2
9K1,A3
9K1,A4 
9K1,A5 
A2,B2
B2,A2
B2,C2
C2,B2
C2,D2
A5,B5
B5,C5
B5,A5
9K1,A6
A6,B6
B6,A6
B6,C6
```

Below is required and expected output which is needed(another file) :

```
9K1,A1
9K1,A2,B2,C2,D2
9K1,A3
9K1,A4
9K1,A5,B5,C5
9K1,A6,B6,C6
```

Code used :

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
    assoc[$1]=$2
    next
}
(FNR!=1)&&($1~/9K/){
    printf "%s,%s", $1,$2
    seen[$1]; seen[$2]
    search=$2
    while((search in assoc) && !(assoc[search] in seen)){
        search=assoc[search]
        printf ",%s", search
        seen[search]
    }
    print ""
    for(var in seen){
         delete seen[var]
    }
}' input.csv input.csv > output.csv
```

Output returned by above code: (which is not as per expectation)

```
9K1,A3,
9K1,A4,
9K1,A5,
9K1,A6,
```

Comment: `NR==FNR` are normaly used when you have more than one file input.  With only one file `NR` will always be equal `FNR` and true, so not needed.

Comment: There is something not clear here. You have duplicates on column 1. Let's take line 8 as example. `BGL_BAM_910_1AC_B_CASR920R879` has value `BGL_BAM_912_2AC_B_CASR920R879` on column 2. Searching value `BGL_BAM_912_2AC_B_CASR920R879` in column 1 gives us two rows (line 9 and 10) with different values on column2. Which one should we take?

Comment: I have different questions then : 2nd line : why `9K1,A2,B1` and not `9K1,A2,B2` ? 3rd line, why `9K2,A2` instead of `9K2,A2,B1` or `9K2,A2,B2` ? 4th line, why `9K2,A3` and not `9K2,A3,C1,D1` ?

Comment: Can you explain, as simply and clearly as possible, how your desired output is derived from that input?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
awk '
NR==FNR{
    assoc[$1]=$2
    next
}
(FNR!=1)&&($1~/9K/){         
    printf "%s,%s", $1,$2
    seen[$1]; seen[$2]
    search=$2 
    while((search in assoc) && !(assoc[search] in seen)){
        search=assoc[search]
        printf ",%s", search
        seen[search]
    }
    print ""
    for(var in seen){ 
         delete seen[var]
    }
}' inputfile.csv inputfile.csv > output.csv
```

Gives :

```
BGL_0BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR176,BGL_KMR_919_1AC_B_CASR920R899
BGL_0BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR176,BGL_CHT_903_1AC_B_CASR920R879,BGL_BAM_910_1AC_B_CASR920R879,BGL_BAM_912_2AC_B_CASR920R879,BGL_BAM_912_1AC_B_CASR920R879
BGL_0BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR176,BGL_0UT_901_1AC_CASR903R551
BGL_0BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR176,BGL_YOT_919_1AC_CASR903R458
BGL_0BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR176,BGL_0BC_901_1AC_T_CASR920R504
BGL_2BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR124,BGL_BGM_908_1AC_CASR903R173
BGL_2BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR124,BGL_ABT_932_1AC_CASR903R963
BGL_2BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR124,BGL_2BC_901_1AC_T_CASR920R948
BGL_2BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR124,BGL_2BC_901_1AC_T_CASR920R948
BGL_2BC_901_1AG_A_CASR9KTR124,BGL_ABT_918_1AC_CASR903R963
```

About

> There is something not clear here. You have duplicates on column 1.
>   Let's take line 8 as example. BGL_BAM_910_1AC_B_CASR920R879 has value
>   BGL_BAM_912_2AC_B_CASR920R879 on column 2. Searching value
>   BGL_BAM_912_2AC_B_CASR920R879 in column 1 gives us two rows (line 9
>   and 10) with different values on column2. Which one should we take?

I took the last row that matches the value of column2 in column1. I can adapt the code if needed.

Could you give me the expected output of this :

```
9K1,A1
9K1,A2
A2,B1
A2,B2
A3,C1
A3,C2
9K2,A2
9K2,A3
9K2,A3
9K2,A3
9K2,C1
C1,D1
C2,D2
```

Comment: we have to consider line number 10 value..because line number 9 we have already picked from column 2 from line number 6 and have checked for its presence in column 1. Same needs to be consider for all the cases.

Comment: Corentin Limier..we have only one input file, all these column 1 and column 2 are in same file and have to do lookup for values in one file(column1 and column2) but output we need in another file..

Comment: @as6656 I know that there is just one file, I parse twice the same file because it is easier in your case.  I edited for clearness. Your rule is still not clear to me, what if the two values were already picked on previous rows ? what if the two values were never picked before ? Which one has priority ?

Comment: Not getting the correct output with your code...basically beginning of every line i need strings value that has 9K in them followed by other strings..
if the two values are already picked i believe it means our code has already processed it and have checked the corresponding row value in column 2.. if the value never picked..then we have to consider it and have to process and look for its corresponding value in column 2... hope i am able to clear your query this time..if not please let me know

Comment: I edited and added the `9K` filter. I still don't understand your priority order so I created an example, please edit your question with it and give me the expected output.

Comment: Corentin Limier .. As per recommendation edited question..please check now..
output received from code is not as per expectation.. please check question for expected output required

Comment: Corentin Limier..have again edited my question with new input file and expected output..please check..hope this time i am able to make you understand my query...
Hope your query is also cleared